# typescript 2.4.2 "or" type strange behaviour

Tags: typescript

I found strange behaviour in "or" types. Don't know, if it is a bug or feature...
What I want to achieve: my variable should only allow an object with the property 'data' OR an object with the property 'records'. But not an object with both 'data' and 'property'.
So:

```
type X = {
  data: string
};
type Y = {
  records: {
    [recordId: number]: {
      [attributeName: string]: any,
    }
  },
};

type XorY = X | Y;


let a:XorY = {
  data: 'something',
  records: {
    12: {
      someKey: 'someValue',
    }
  }
};
```

In my opinion, the assignment to a should throw an error. Any ideas, how I can do such a check in ts?

Comment: Usually, `|` means `OR`, and `^` means XOR. Where `OR` is inclusive, and `XOR` is exclusive. You yourself say it's an `OR`, so I'm a bit confused as to why you'd think `XOR` would be used here? I can see the utility in having exclusive unions, but I think that inclusive unions are useful far more often. Think about all the existing JavaScript libraries which have functions that can take a string, OR an element. Hopefully adding your support to the github issue I linked will help show them how much interest there is in the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union types are currently inclusive only, which is to say if any of the conditions are true, then it's a match.

It is not currently possible to create an exclusive union.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094) discussing adding exclusive unions which you might want to participate in if this is a feature you desire strongly.

> Proposal: Allow exclusive unions using logical or (^) operator between types #14094